# Canvas rectangles are blurry

Tags: canvas, blurry

I need to make a table of pixels of rather big size. I used canvas, but encountered a problem: all pixels are blurry. It is not very well noticed on 100% scale, but if I make it x2 or more, it becomes very clear, that something is wrong. And finally I want it to render well on scales up to x10-x15.
I have such code:

```
        <style>
            body
            {
                background: rgb(207, 207, 207);
                overflow-x: hidden;
            }
            #main
            {
                position: absolute;
                left: 0;
                top: 0;
                height: 100%;
                width: calc(100% - 250px);
                background: lime;
            }
            canvas
            {
                width: 3180px;
                height: 800px;
                position: absolute;
                border: 2px solid black;
                left: 50%;
                top: 50%;
                transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body id='body'>
        <div id='main'>
            <canvas id="canvas" width='3180px' height='800px'></canvas>
        </div>
        <!--<div id='menu'></div>-->
        <script>
            var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
            var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
            const colors = ["#FFFFFF", "#C2C2C2", "#858585", "#474747", "#000000", "#3AAFFF", "#71AAEB", "#4a76a8", "#074BF3", "#5E30EB", "#FF6C5B", "#FE2500", 
                "#FF218B", "#99244F", "#4D2C9C", "#FFCF4A", "#FEB43F", "#FE8648", "#FF5B36", "#DA5100", "#94E044", "#5CBF0D", "#C3D117", "#FCC700", "#D38301"];
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 3180, 800);
            for (let i = 0; i < 400; i++)
            {
                for (let j = 0; j < 1590; j++)
                {
                    ctx.fillStyle = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
                    ctx.fillRect(j * 2, 2 * i, 2, 2);
                }
            }
        </script>
```

I tried to search for the solution, but nothing I found helped. [image: here is the part of the table I made on scale ~x7]

Comment: DOM image content is smoothed when up-scaled. You can change that behavior by setting the CSS rule `#canvas { image-rendering: pixelated; }`

Comment: oh, it was so easy to fix. Thanks a lot. I have spent nearly 2 hours searching for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments to the post, DOM image content is smoothed when up-scaled. You can change that behavior by setting the CSS rule #canvas { image-rendering: pixelated; }

So, to fix the blur behavior you have to add `#canvas { image-rendering: pixelated; }` to your CSS. Worked for me.